# Code changes in the Source file(.cs) not reflected in the application

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a website that I have to migrate to our servers with few code changes. Here is the scenario:

We have a website that was written by some other Vendor and now we have to migrate that website to a different server with some minor code changes. The problem is that they have a custom dll sat Test.dll which has a file say Person.cs, now that file is also present as a source file in the website(Project) which is required because we have to make changes to it or might have to in future. But when I make changes in the source code of Person.cs I don't see those changes reflected in my application because it is picking up the Person.cs file from the dll which after reading some online posts and document is how .net works although java works the other way.

I am very new to .net so cant think of a solution here any comments or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you correct, you should build your project with that changes in order to get dll file and replace old with the new one. IIS will notice that dll is changed and reload it.

Comment: Its a website not a project so the source code changes will not be added to the dll

Comment: So you have the ASP.NET MVC application which was successfully deployed and now you want to make some changes in it but you haven't got full VS _solution_ (or _project_), only a set of source *.cs files?

Comment: Yes, the only thing to add so that you have all the information is that i have a set of source files (.CS) but they are also part of the dll(don't know why) but my guess is that since mvc project is a web project that creates dll when source code is compiled, but then they did not give us the .csproj file that comes with every asp.net project. Very confusing I know

Answer (score 1):

If it is a web *project*, the c# code is compiled during project build. To get your changes to take you will need to rebuild the project, generating new binaries.

Comment: It is a website not a web project, so when I do a rebuild new dll is not generated, also I think it might sound weird but why would you have a source file and a dll with the same file, you should have files in dll that you dont want to modify in the same project/website just it is in java.

Answer (score 0):

What likely happened is your vendor didn't supply you with a solution (.sln) file. You probably need to start with a blank web site. It's difficult to determine if this is a webforms or mvc site due to the limited amount of information.

Comment: Actually, OP clearly specified that it is ASP.NET _website_ project

Comment: this is going to sound strange but it is a MVC project but it does not have a .csproj so I had to create a website and then drop in all the files i had

Answer (score 0):

I created a website to host WCF service in IIS. I created profile to publish website and make my life easy. I didnt want to drag drop DLLs from WCF service to website so I put a condition that compile code before every publish.

The code for profile looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>x86</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\TestWebsite</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The line which make sure that the code is compiled prior to publishing:

```
<PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
```